# Server not available on localhost with response code 403 & RuntimeError in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

After changing proxy settings in open_uri.rb and server_manage.rb I finally managed to  install neo4j behind a proxy server. The neo4j server is running on port 7000 ( It opens in the browser) but when i enter :

```
$rails generate scaffold post title body
```

**Error**:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/neo4j-core-5.1.6/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb:51:in `open': Server not available on  http://localhost:7000 (response code 403) (RuntimeError)
```

What should I do ?
Any help is appreciated!!

```
 $ ruby --version
 ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

 $ rails --version
 Rails 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess - proxy issues. Things may behave differently in your browser and code (because those are 2 different environment).

To check what exactly is going on with your database, you should try to make request to Neo4j manually, from command line.

Example with using `curl`:

```
# if auth enabled
curl -i --user username:password http://localhost:7000/db/data/
# if auth disabled
curl -i http://localhost:7000/db/data/
```

This will give you more details on what exactly is not working.

Also you can assemble basic ruby script that will make HTTP request, to check what you receive in response in this case.

Comment: I see you marked it as correct. What did this show you, what change(s) did you have to make to get things working?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 might mean that your Neo4j authentication credentials are wrong. See http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/5.1.x/Setup.html#rails-configuration for details but basically, adding something like this to `application.rb` might do the trick:

```
config.neo4j.session_options = { basic_auth: { username: 'foo', password: 'bar'} }
```

Also, since you mentioned needing help with the proxy, you can add an `initialize` key to set that.

```
init = { proxy: { uri: 'http://myproxy', user: 'username', password: 'password' }}
auth = { username: 'neo4j', password: 'pwhere'}
config.neo4j.session_options = { basic_auth: auth, initialize: init }
```

Comment: Since I installed Neo4j using rake the basic authentication is disabled. I even checked that in the config file for neo4j.  Changing the proxy made no difference, I am still getting the same error.